# Is there a way to have Postgres tell you what a syntax error was in addition to what it is at/near?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've tried setting 'log_min_error_statement' equal to debug5 in postgresql.conf but I'm still getting the standard "PostgreSQL said: syntax error at or near "AS"" error message in both the console and the postgresql log.

Comment: `log_min_error_statement` controls what messages to log, not how detailed they should be.

Comment: Can you include in your question the exact statement that you're executing and the exact error message you're getting? When there's a syntax error, a parser can know there's an error (an unexpected text at a specific place), but it cannot know what the error can be related to.

Comment: Thank you @zerkms! @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I ended up figuring it out. Turns out it was really obvious syntax error. I just didn't notice it because of how long my statement was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PostgreSQL knew what the error was it'd tell you, at least in most cases.

If it just says "Syntax error at or near ..." it doesn't know what you meant, and can't guess what's wrong. It's a parse error. It could offer a (very long) list of suggestions, but that'd make error messages absurdly verbose, like:

```
postgres=# SELECT AS fred ORDER BY 1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT AS fred ORDER BY 1;
```

Yup, that's a syntax error, because it doesn't make sense on any level. What's wrong with it? How do you succinctly describe that? How does a parser even tell what's wrong?

```
postgres=# SELECT AS fred ORDER BY 1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT AS fred ORDER BY 1;
HINT: typo?
HINT: Did you use a reserved keyword as an identifier without "quoting" it? Like "AS"?
HINT: Did you leave out the value before the AS keyword?
HINT: ... endless possibilities ...
```

Occasionally a parser can guess something you might've done wrong. PostgreSQL's parser tries to tell you when it can, e.g.

```
psql -c "SELECT 'openquote";
ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'openquote"
LINE 1: SELECT 'openquote
```